# How to get a string of the FEN position

Tags: python, chess, python-chess, fen

After I do

```
import chess
board = chess.Board()
```

how can I have a string with the FEN of the position? In other words, how can I extract from `board` the FEN of the position as a string, with the same output as if I did

```
a='rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1'
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`fen`](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/v0.24.1/core.html#chess.Board.fen) function.

```
board = chess.Board()
a = board.fen()
```